# There is a pdf viewer which rotates the pdf files when you open them?

Tags: pdf-reader, rotate

The questions is in the title :)
SO, there is a pdf viewer which rotates the pdf files when you open them?

I have lots of scanned pdf files which needs to be rotated when I open them to verify something and I'm tired of pressing "ctrl+shift+=". So, help me!

Answer (score 2):

You can use some pdf tool which will rotate all your .pdf's in a batch. Something like [pdfedit](http://pdfedit.cz/en/index.html) for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Adobe Acrobat Pro's Batch Processing feature to rotate your PDFs permanently.

#### Setup

1. Place all of your PDFs in a new folder. Open one of the PDFs in Acrobat.
2. Go to **Advanced** > **Document Processing** > **Batch Processing** > **New Sequence**.
3. Name the sequence **Rotate All Pages**. Click OK.
4. Click **Select Commands** > **Page** (expand folder) > **Rotate Pages** > **Add**.
5. Click the *tiny arrow* to the left of "Rotate Pages."
6. Double-click on **Pages**. Set **Direction** according to your preference. Set **Page Range** to All.
7. Select another option for the *Pages of any orientation* drop-down menu if you wish to apply the rotation only on landscape or portrait pages. Click OK.
8. Click the menu beside **Run commands on**. Choose **Selected Folder** and pick the folder that contains your PDFs.
9. Choose an output location. Click **Output Options** if you want to change the file naming conventions or if you want the output PDF to replace the original. Click OK.

#### Running the Sequence

1. Select **Rotate All Pages**.
2. Click **Run Sequence** > **OK**.

Comment: Acrobat Pro is not so free, and I guess that there are enough free tool out there that can do the trick at least as good as the acrobat.

Answer (score 0):

I would doubt that there is a program that will always open a pdf sideways, but if you have adobe acrobat, you can add the documents to a single pdf file, then change the view (rotate) and it should change it for all the pages.

Comment: What do you mean. Can you be more specific. I added them to a portfolio and then.... ?

Comment: Edited answer, made a mistake sorry.